# GCC vs. clang: direct-list-initialization error

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang++

I'm a little bit confused about the following. I want to run this code

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    int number{12};
    std::cout << "Hello World.";
    std::cout << "My number was: " << number << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I have installed *g++ (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0_4) 10.2.0* via brew and *clang* via xCode.

```
g++ --version
g++ (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0_4) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

clang --version
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I can compile and run the code above with g++ but not with *clang*. When compiling with *clang* I get the following error:

```
clang++ my_first_program.cpp 
my_first_program.cpp:12:12: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
        int number{12};
                  ^
                  ;
1 error generated.
```

The problem seems to be the direct-list-initialization in line 4. So my question is:

**Why do I get an error when compiling with clang? What is the problem with direct-list-initialization?**

Thank you very much for your support in advance.

Comment: Add `-std=c++11`?

Comment: Yep, Apple's clang defaults to C++98, I think. Always specify your standard anyway.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you. I'm new in C++ and you helped me a lot.